# How do i get many to many relationship of JPA to work with kotlin ? LazyInitializationException

Tags: hibernate, kotlin, jpa, many-to-many, lazy-initialization

I just cant wrap my head around it. I have read everything there is to read but i cannot get it to work. It is a very simple SQL structure:

I got following tables

```
create table currencies
(
    id INT auto_increment,
    isoAlpha VARCHAR(3) not null,
    isoNumeric VARCHAR(3) not null,
    name VARCHAR(100) not null,
    constraint currencies_pk
        primary key (id)
);
```

then

```
create table countries
(
    id INT auto_increment,
    isoAlpha VARCHAR(3) not null,
    isoNumeric VARCHAR(3) not null,
    name VARCHAR(100) not null,
    constraint countries_pk
        primary key (id)
);
```

and finally the mm table to connect those two:

```
create table mm_currency_country
(
    currency INT not null,
    country INT not null
);
```

Inside my Kotlin code i defined the entities as following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "currencies")
data class Currency (

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    val id: Int,

    @Column(nullable = false)
    val isoAlpha: String,

    @Column(nullable = false)
    val isoNumeric: Int,

    @Column(nullable = false)
    val name: String,

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "mm_currency_country",
        joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "currency", referencedColumnName = "id")],
        inverseJoinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "country", referencedColumnName = "id")])
    val countries: Set<Country>
)
```

and the other one

```
@Entity
@Table(name="countries")
data class Country (
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    val id: Int,

    @Column(nullable = false)
    val isoAlpha: String,

    @Column(nullable = false)
    val isoNumeric: Int,

    @Column(nullable = false)
    val name: String,

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "countries")
    val currencies: Set<Currency>
)
```

I am using a simple CrudRepository to fetch the currency data

```
@Repository
interface RepoCurrencies: CrudRepository<Currency,Int>
```

When i use the `findAll()` function i get all the registered currencies, but the countries list (in debugger view) is filled only with `LazyInitializationException` errors. It seems i need some kind of `EntityGraph` to get this to work... but all my attempts to implement this failed so far. Could someone please give me a bit of guidance through this ? Does every many to many relation always throw this error or is it just a matter of luck ?! This seems pretty basic, and hibernate cant handle it out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

`@ManyToMany` relations are fetched lazily by default, which means your currency objects hold proxies for the countries property which load the countries from the database when you access them, e.g. by iterating over the set. To do so, you need an active session. Try annotating the method which calls `findAll()` and accesses the countries property with `@Transactional`.

Comment: First of all thank you for the reply. I tried to annotate the method that calls the `findAll()` with `@Transactional`. That way i get a `StackOverflowError` preceeded by about a hundred logger warnings `HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@3d49da33<rs=HikariProxyResultSet@930972797 wrapping org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.com.read.resultset.SelectResultSet@5bc618bb>`. When i debug the object just keeps loading endlessly...